# Change function prefix name in caption with algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e

`\SetAlgorithmName` changes the prefix that comes in caption with `\begin{algorithm}...\caption{lol...}\end{algorithm}` from `\usepackage{algorithm2e}`.

But how to change that prefix/name for functions?  Procedures?  Etc?  Is there `\SetFunctionName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exist

```tex
\SetAlgoProcName{a name}{an autoref name}
\SetAlgoFuncName{a name}{an autoref name}
```

see the [user manual of `algorithm2e`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf) v5.2, sec. 6, page 17 (near the end of that page).